# Applying Suzuki-Trotter approximation to a Quantum Circuit in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, trotterization

I am trying to apply the Suzuki-Trotter approximation to a quantum circuit in Qiskit. However, when I attempt to use the st.synthesize() method on my quantum circuit, I encounter the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'operator'
```

Here is the relevant code part:

```
for j in range(0, N_qubit, 2):
    H = (U * Z^Z) - (J * X^X) - (J * Y^Y)
    pauli_ev_gate = PauliEvolutionGate(H, time=t)
    if j != N_qubit - 1:
        qc.append(pauli_ev_gate, [j, j+1])

for j in range(1, N_qubit, 2):
    H = (U * Z^Z) - (J * X^X) - (J * Y^Y)
    pauli_ev_gate = PauliEvolutionGate(H, time=t)
    if j != N_qubit - 1:
        qc.append(pauli_ev_gate, [j, j+1])

for j in range(N_qubit):
    pauli_ev_gate = PauliEvolutionGate(h[j]*Z, time=t)
    qc.append(pauli_ev_gate, [j])
    
    
  
st = SuzukiTrotter(order=2, reps=6)
qc = st.synthesize(qc)
```

I want to apply the Suzuki-Trotter approximation to my quantum circuit after adding the gates. How can I resolve the AttributeError and successfully apply the Suzuki-Trotter transformation to my circuit?

Also if someone can  explain does it matter to apply SuzukiTrotter transformation on each gate individually or on the whole circuit, it'd be quite helpful.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`SuzukiTrotter.synthesize()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.synthesis.SuzukiTrotter.synthesize.html) takes an instance of [`PauliEvolutionGate`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PauliEvolutionGate.html) as a parameter. The issue in your code is that you are passing a `QuantumCircuit`.

The right way to use `SuzukiTrotter.synthesize()`:

- Define your Hamiltonian as one of the operator classes supported
  by `PauliEvolutionGate` . e.g., [`SparsePauliOp`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.SparsePauliOp.html)
- Create a `PauliEvolutionGate`. Set its `operator` parameter to be that Hamiltonian.
- Pass the gate to `SuzukiTrotter.synthesize()`

As an example, assume that we have the Hamiltonian:
$$H =  -J \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} Z_i Z_{i+1} + h\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i$$
We can define it using the following code snippet:

```
from qiskit.circuit import Parameter
from qiskit.quantum_info import Pauli, SparsePauliOp
import numpy as np

J = Parameter("J")
h = Parameter("h")

N = 4
pauli_list = []
coeffs = []
for i in range(N - 1):
    x_p = np.zeros(N, dtype=bool)
    z_p = np.zeros(N, dtype=bool)
    z_p[i] = True
    z_p[i + 1] = True
    pauli_list.append(Pauli((z_p, x_p)))
    coeffs.append(-J)

for i in range(N):
    x_p = np.zeros(N, dtype=bool)
    z_p = np.zeros(N, dtype=bool)
    x_p[i] = True
    pauli_list.append(Pauli((z_p, x_p)))
    coeffs.append(h)

H = SparsePauliOp(pauli_list, coeffs=coeffs)

# assign J & h values:
H = H.assign_parameters({ J: 1, h: 1 })
```

Now we create the evolution gate:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import PauliEvolutionGate

gate = PauliEvolutionGate(H)
```

Finally, we synthesize it:

```
from qiskit.synthesis import SuzukiTrotter

st = SuzukiTrotter(order=2, reps=6)
circ = st.synthesize(gate)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped.

Comment: Can you also say how to choose SuzukitTrotter order is bigger order always more precise?

Comment: Qiskit documentation for [`SuzukiTrotter`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.synthesis.SuzukiTrotter.html) is a good starting point. And it contains references for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The docs here https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.synthesis.SuzukiTrotter.synthesize.html state that the synthesize method takes a `PauliEvolutionGate` and returns a `QuantumCircuit` implementing the evolution

Comment: Yes I know that I was wondering how can I apply this transform to overal circuit instead of individual gates. And does it matter? Does applying SuzikiTrotter to overal circuit differes from applying it to individual terms? -Since it's not linear transform I am unsure(When operators do not commute-